# mudar connection webconfig mysql + .NET

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework

Eu tenho esse site usando entity framework funcionando normalmente em banco mysql localhost, agora eu quero colocar em um servidor, já tentei mudar varias vezes a conneciton string, mas ele dá dois erros que eu listarei abaixo, imagino que esses erros tenha haver com a senha, já que no localhost não tem senha, eu tentei colocar a senha com "password='senha'" e "pwd='senha'"

**ERROS**

MySqlException: Access denied for user 'meuusario'@'ipdobanco' (using password: NO)

MySqlException: Authentication to host 'den1.mysql1.gear.host' for user 'meuusario' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'meuusario'@'ipdobanco' (using password: NO)

**Connection atual**

```
<add name="kiccConnectionString" connectionString="server=localhost;user id=root;persistsecurityinfo=False;database=kicc" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />

<add name="kiccEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ModelProduto.csdl|res://*/ModelProduto.ssdl|res://*/ModelProduto.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;user id=root;database=kicc&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

<add name="kiccEntitiesBanco" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ModelProduto.csdl|res://*/ModelProduto.ssdl|res://*/ModelProduto.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;user id=root;persistsecurityinfo=False;database=kicc&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

    <add name="kiccEntitiesProjeto" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ModelBanco.csdl|res://*/ModelBanco.ssdl|res://*/ModelBanco.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;user id=root;database=kicc&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: a primeira, é a que funciona, certo ? o que são as 3 outras ?

Comment: acredito que seja do entity Framework.

Answer (score 1):

Supondo que a senha desse usuário esteja correta, 
a mensagem de erro:

> MySqlException: Access denied for user 'meuusario'@'ipdobanco' (using
>   password: NO)

Isso pode significar que o usuário não tem permissão para se conectar ao servidor 'localhost'.

Este link pode te ajudar. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41609572/mysqlexception-access-denied-for-user-altjenblocalhost-using-password-ye)
Caso não saiba como dar a permissão tem esse link tambem. [link](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-grant-all-privileges-on-a-database-in-mysql/)

Comment: eu vou ler esses dois links, mas só pra avisar eu quero deixar esse banco em um servidor, não em localhost, usando um banco gratuito desse site https://my.gearhost.com/Databases/Details/coppula  o banco ta assim lá tem o print nesse link: http://prntscr.com/qxmqk3